# Model inside a subfolder within models folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Ruby on Rails 2.3.8 and I'd like to know how to organize models in subfolders so Ruby can recognize them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To the best of my understanding, you need to namespace your models in order for them to be loaded.

to use the generator:

```
> ./script/generate model Customer::Address
```

will create the model in `app/models/customer/address.rb`

```
class Customer::Address

end
```

It will load recursively, but in order for rails to find it, it will need to have the namespace that lines up with the path.

Fair warning that when you use the generator (at least in rails 2.3.5 and lower is all I have tested this in).  It will create table name as `customer_addresses`, but the model will by default still look for a table name of `addresses`.  You will either need to change the migration database name to addresses or add `set_table_name 'customers_addresses'` or similar to get the two to line up.

Answer (score 3):

Rails will load all models in /app/models recursively from subdirectories (for Ruby 2.0+). You can split them into logical subdirectories: database, users, customers, etc

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 5 , If the Model was in Models/customer/address.rb

You access it with

```
Customer::Address.all
```

Answer (score 0):

To then call the model I had to reference it like this, ::Customer::Address.all, not sure why it requires the leading ::